# Loop through database and run shell commands with Python and exiftool

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, mysql

Briefly, I'm looking at getting the code below to execute faster. I have 100k images to go through. I'm running a query against MySQL, looping through results and then running exiftool against an image, then moving it.

I started running it and it quickly became evident it wouldn't be a quick thing :-(

```
import mysql.connector
import os

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',database='database', password='password')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT post_title,Event,File,Name from a order by File")

cursor.execute(query)

def shellquote(s):
    return s.replace("'", "")

for (post_title, Event,File,Name) in cursor:
    olddir = r'/home/alan/Downloads/OLD/'
    newdir = r'/home/alan/Downloads/NEW/' + post_title

    oldfile = olddir + File
    newfile = newdir + "/"+File

    if not os.path.exists(newfile):
        os.makedirs(newfile)
    if os.path.isfile(oldfile): 
        print " > PROCESSING: " + oldfile
        os.system("exiftool -q "+shellquote(oldfile)+" -xmp:title='"+shellquote(post_title)+"'")
        os.system("exiftool -q "+shellquote(oldfile)+" -xmp:description='"+shellquote(Name)+" courtesy of https://www.festivalflyer.com'")
        os.system("exiftool -q "+shellquote(oldfile)+" -description='"+shellquote(Name)+" courtesy of https://www.festivalflyer.com'")
        os.rename(oldfile, newfile)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

I tried using subprocess but for whatever reason, I didn't get it to run. Any advice is welcome.

I suppose I could move the 3 lines of `exiftool` commands to just one and pass multiple arguments. I also saw `-stay_open` as an option to `exiftool` but not sure how to apply it

Comment: maybe https://github.com/smarnach/pyexiftool can be of some help

Comment: I looked at that but it was mostly getting tags rather than writing

Comment: I’d use something like `with exiftool.ExifTool() as et: for ...: et.execute("-q " + oldfile, "-xmp:title='"+shellquote(post_title)+"'", "-xmp:description='{}' courtesy of ...".format(shellquote(Name)), "-description='{}' courtesy of ...".format(shellquote(Name)))`

Comment: @pee2pee please undelete https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208118/php-optimise-code-that-does-a-reconciliation-between-two-arrays-based-on-numer . I was in the middle of typing up my answer when it was suddenly deleted.

Answer (score 4):

1. Close your connection to your database, even if there's an error. Use a try-finally to do this.
2. Make some functions, moving the database stuff into it's own function makes it much easier to read.
3. From [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) docs:

   > The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) documentation for some helpful recipes.
4. You may want to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for various file related things, such as `os.path.join` to join path sections.
5. `print` is slow. Try removing it for a massive speed up.

And so you may want to start changing your code to look like:

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import subprocess


def read_database():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', database='database', password='password')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    try:
        query = ("SELECT post_title,Event,File,Name from a order by File")
        cursor.execute(query)
        for item in cursor:
            yield item
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()


def main():
    path = os.path
    old_dir = r'/home/alan/Downloads/OLD/'
    new_dir = r'/home/alan/Downloads/NEW/'
    for (post_title, event, file_name, name) in read_database():
        old_file = path.join(old_dir, file_name)
        new_file = path.join(new_dir, post_title, file_name)
        if not path.exists(new_file):
            os.makedirs(new_file)
        if path.isfile(old_file):
            subprocess.call(["exiftool", "-q", old_file, "-xmp:title='" + post_title.replace("'", "") + "'"])
            subprocess.call(["exiftool", "-q", old_file, "-xmp:description='" + name.replace("'", "") + " courtesy of https://www.festivalflyer.com'"])
            subprocess.call(["exiftool", "-q", old_file, "-description='" + name.replace("'", "") + " courtesy of https://www.festivalflyer.com'"])
            os.rename(old_file, new_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two pointers in addition to the answer by Peilonrayz:

- *Why the repetition of `os.makedirs(new_file)`?* – Your code as it stands has a fixed new directory, and then you test for a presumably non-existently file with `os.path.exists(newfile)`, before calling the `makedirs()`. Given that `File` doesn't have any directory parts, you'll call `makedirs()` trying to *recreate* the directory all over again.

  In other words, this could be done once in front of the loop, and never done again. And triggering os calls are expensive, so this could save a lot of time. This would reduce from trying to create the directory a 100K times, to 1 time.
- *Reduce subprocess calls whenever possible* – Initiating new subprocesses triggers quite a lot of work, so it's usually well worth to reduce this as much as possible.

  In your case there are two possible options, which might drastically reduce the overhead cost of initiating subprocesses.

  1. Join the three `exiftool` commands into one command. This could potentially reduce your cost of number of started subprocesses from 300K to 100K times. Depending on the cost of actually running the `exiftool` command, this could reduce running times upto a third.
  2. Consider gathering all the `exiftool` into a batch file, which you execute after processing all the database output. This wouldn't reduce the running time of the `exiftool` command but you wouldn' start a new subprocess a 100K times, but just once when running the batch file.

So in general, always try reducing the number of subprocesses started, as they are quite expensive. And `os.system` calls usually triggers subprocesses as well as the `subprocess.call`.